# How to get rootpath when the defines are set in a subdirectory?

Tags: php, directory, filepath

A reliable way to get the actual (full) rootpath when the define is in a subdirectory? Consider:

E:\web\sites\name\index.php
E:\web\sites\name\res\defines.php
E:\web\sites\name\res\another.php
E:\web\sites\name\classes\class-example.php

Where `E:\web\` is localhost and `E:\web\sites\name` is the intended root of the site.

An example path to define = `E:\web\sites\name\data\feature\file.txt`, in the manner of `$file = ROOTPATH."\data\feature\file.txt";`

The reason I don't use relative paths is because I want to pass the path in `classes\class-example.php` and also in `res\another.php` without using two constants for the same target.

So, in res\defines.php, what is the way to get the rootpath to point to `E:\web\sites\name\`? When the website is on a server, the same ROOTPATH should point to `http://www.example.com/`

Here's what I get when defines.php is in `res\defines.php`:

```
// Outputs: E:\web\sites\name\res
echo __DIR__;

// Outputs: E:\web\sites\name\res
echo realpath(__DIR__);

// Outputs: sites\name\res\another.php
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

// Outputs: E:\web
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

// Outputs: sites\name\res\another.php
echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

// Outputs: E:\web\sites\name\res\defines.php
echo __FILE__;

// Outputs: sites\name\res\another.php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use: `dirname(__DIR__)` (PHP >= 5.3.0).

```
// Outputs: E:\web\sites\name
echo dirname(__DIR__);
```

Note that there are questions that are slightly like this, but none of those that I checked had the information about `dirname(__DIR__)`; they all only mentioned `dirname(__FILE__)` which does **not** output the same thing as `dirname(__DIR__)` - the `__FILE__` version outputs `E:\web\sites\name\res`

Hopefully this info helps others with a similar problem regarding subdirectories :)

It would be interesting to hear if someone has a solution for older PHP versions too, in case someone is using one...